# Receiving Focus Change Events for a dynamic TableRow

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow, focusable

I have a TableLayout that is focusable.
I dynamically add to TableRows to this TableLayout.

Although I can get the TableRow, and its contents (a few TextViews), to respond to Touch events, I can't get any of them to respond to Focus events.

Aside from setting a OnFocusChangeListener, is there anything else I need to do?

```
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this); // "this" is a valid Context...
tableRow.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

TextView someNameTextView = new TextView(this);
someNameTextView.setText("Foo");
someNameTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
tableRow.addView(someNameTextView);

tableRow.setOnFocusChangeListener(someRowFocusChangeListener);
someNameTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(someRowFocusChangeListener);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong component for the UI interaction I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually calling `setFocusable` (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setFocusable%28boolean%29) on the `View`s and `TableRow`s?

Comment: Femi, I did. Just to test things out, I changed the TextView instances to EditText instances, and the focus worked just fine. I'm thinking maybe I need to move away from the TableLayout, and stick with ListViews.